# Upgrading JSTL 1.1 to 1.2 fails with java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext

Tags: tomcat, jstl, tomcat7

i getting error when i using JSTL. Please to help me.

i using jstl-impl-1.2.jar and jstl-api-1.2.jar in my tomcat 7 and i take out standard.jsp and jstl.jsp but still hitting this error.

Error code

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()Ljavax/el/ELContext;
javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.unExposeVariables(LoopTagSupport.java:624)
```

Web.xml

```
<web-app 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `/WEB-INF/lib`, or worse, your `JRE/lib` or `JRE/lib/ext`, is polluted with servletcontainer-specific libraries like `jsp-api.jar` of a different and older-versioned servletcontainer make/version. You need to get rid of them in your webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`. Those libraries are supposed to be already provided by the servletcontainer itself, which is in your case Tomcat.

In your particular example, the [`javax.servlet.jsp.PageContext.getELContext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#getELContext%28%29) method, which exist since JSP 2.1 only, is requested by Tomcat's internal classes, but it could not be found in the JSP API, because you've an older versioned one (apparently JSP 2.0 or older) in your webapp which got precedence in classloading over Tomcat's own one.

In other words, your Tomcat 7 was running like as tomcat 5.5 or older all the time until you upgraded JSTL to a Tomcat 6 compatible one.

#### See also:

- [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project/4076706#4076706)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like versioning problem,maybe a conflicting jar file of some sort. See [this](http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/JstlTagLibDefinitions) may help.